# how to override a dependent assembly

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

I have a class library ( .net framework 4.7.2) that has a nuget package   [Microsoft.Azure.DataLake.Store](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.DataLake.Store/1.2.5-alpha)  which has a dependent assembly of Newtonsoft.Json (>= 6.0.8)

I want to use  Newtonsoft.Json version 13.0.1

Class library does not have a config - Do I need to add a binding redirect  to every project that references the class Lib?

Thanks, Peter

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you can try this way to change the version of nuget packages in different projects in the same solution.

You can update it by right clicking on the solution and selecting Manage NuGet Packages for Solution and selecting the packages and version and projects to install.

This method can use to upgrade the version of Newtonsoft.Json that Microsoft.Azure.DataLake.Store depends on.
[image]